# Django 2 to 3 upgrade throws error: "on_delete must be callable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-3.0

In upgrading from Django 2 to 3.2, upon running my server, I suddenly get the following error:

```
TypeError: on_delete must be callable.
```

The model field in question is this one:

```
game_played = models.ForeignKey(Game, "Game Played", help_text="Game Played", null=True, blank=False)
```

As you can see, `on_delete` is not called on this field. Reverting back to Django 2 fixes this issue in that it no longer returns the error. I have tried to add `on_delete` to the field, which results in this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'on_delete'
```

I have reviewed the Django 3 docs and cannot find anything related to changes to `on_delete` that would affect this. All I can find regarding `on_delete` issues are that sometimes people put `models.CASCADE` in quotes versus making it callable but that is not the issue here.

How would I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to provide the argument for `on_delete` one cannot forego it. Also the second argument for the `__init__` of `ForeignKey` is not the `verbose_name` which you are assuming, instead it is `on_delete`, hence you should pass `verbose_name` as a kwarg if you need to:

```
# pass `verbose_name` as kwarg
# pass `on_delete` it cannot be foregone
game_played = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Game Played", help_text="Game Played", null=True, blank=False)
```

> **Note**: Don't know why you don't get this error in Django 2, looking at the source code the second argument is also `on_delete` in that
> version, should have given you some error at least at the time of
> deletion if not at instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

Just add on_delete, and i don't think you need "Game Played", so it will look like this:

```
game_played = models.ForeignKey(Game, help_text="Game Played", null=True, blank=False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Then makemigrations and migrate in your terminal